# how to replace new line characters while selecting from HIVE table

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a AVRO format table in HIVE. One of the column (string data type) in that table contains data with new line characters, so when I am selecting (using beeline or pyspark) I am getting multiple lines. I did tried the option REGEXP_REPLACE(col1,"\n","") in my select, but it is still returning multi lines.

The value for col1 when I copy and paste in a text editor it looks like below:

```
NY - Enjoy holidays or Enjoy leaves.  
Silver 2000 plan
Silver 2000 plan CSR 1
Silver 2000 plan CSR 2
Gold 600 plan
Enjoy, holidays then leaves for ER, UC and old age only.  Primary holidays not subject to Enjoy.
```

What could have been an alternative here?

Comment: what is the value of `col1`

Comment: provided the value in the original post

Answer (score 5):

it resolves with regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col1,'\r',''),'\n','')

Answer (score 0):

try this

> `regexp_replace(col1, '\\\\n', "")`

**Example**

```
hive> select * from temp.test4;
OK
1   abc\nxyz
Time taken: 0.169 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select id, regexp_replace(value, '\\\\n', "") from temp.test4;
OK
1   abcxyz
```

Comment: I am not getting the output correctly. I tried in beeline and newlines are not getting replaced properly. I tried in pyspark and there the value returned as null

Comment: how does value look like in table ? is it the way I represented?

Comment: No. Visually I don't see \n within the data. But when I copy the data and paste it in a text editor then it was showing in multi lines.

Comment: Infact in pyspark it is printing the last line "Enjoy, holidays then leaves for ER, UC and old age only.  Primary holidays not subject to Enjoy." using regexp_replace(col1,'\\n','')

Comment: It was actually carriage return in the data and resolves with regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col1,'\\r',''),'\\n','')